# is it possible to disable intellisense dropdown with monaco editor?

Tags: monaco-editor

is there a way to disable intellisense dropdowns with monaco editor? i'm going to use my own and don't want to use monaco editor's dropdowns. i love the syntax highlighting, but don't need autocomplete dropdowns.

i've looked at the editor options and haven't found anything - https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/interfaces/monaco.editor.ieditoroptions.html#contextmenu

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to register your own completion provider, which does nothing:

`languages.registerCompletionItemProvider("javascript", new DummyCompletionProvider());`

```js
export class DummyCompletionProvider implements languages.CompletionItemProvider {

    public provideCompletionItems(model: editor.ITextModel, position: Position, context: CompletionContext, token: CancellationToken): ProviderResult<CompletionList> {
            return null;
        }
}
```